# How to insert metadata in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I am very new in MongoDB. I want to create a document in MongoDB in this format:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ad60a8b42f59a0066606b8d"),
  "metadata" :{
      "_class" : "eu.ohim.rcd.efi.DocumentEntity",
       "_id" : "RCD201800000001024-0002-0000",
       "provisionalId" : "RCD201800000001024-0002",
       "designApplicationId" : "RCD201800000001024",
        "documentType" : "PROTECTED_VIEW",
         "rcdProtected" : true
   },
   "filename" : "View0000.jpg",
   "aliases" : null,
   "chunkSize" : NumberLong(261120),
   "uploadDate" : ISODate("2018-04-17T14:54:03.782Z"),
   "length" : NumberLong(29179),
   "contentType" : "image/jpeg",
   "md5" : "1402721cc080174ac6ae9c1d51eb68ab"
}
```

Generally when we create a Document we write the Java code like this:

```
   MongoCollection<Document> collection=database.getCollection("rcd");
    Document document=new Document("title","bookstore")
            .append("id", 1)
            .append("description", "Bookstore of cOMPUTER SCIENCE ONLY")
            .append("address", "Sea View Special economic Zone sector-135 Noida")
            .append("phone", "0120213356");
    collection.insertOne(document);
    System.out.println("Document Added sucessfully");
```

Now, I want to append a metadata and its schema. Then what would be the Java code that will insert document in this structure?

Please suggest me.

Comment: It is the same way as you insert any other document. If you are looking for automatic information collection from context and insert then you will have to customize it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The `metadata` is a subdocument, to insert this you append an attribute named `metadata` of type `Document` when preparing your document for instertion.

For example:

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = ...;

// prepare the sub document
Document metadata = new Document("_class", "eu.ohim.rcd.efi.DocumentEntity")
        .append("_id", "RCD201800000001024-0002-0000")
        .append("provisionalId", "RCD201800000001024-0002")
        .append("designApplicationId", "RCD201800000001024")
        .append("documentType", "PROTECTED_VIEW")
        .append("rcdProtected", true);

// prepare the main document
Document document = new Document("filename", "View000.jpg")
        .append("aliases", null)
        .append("chunkSize", 261120L)
        .append("uploadDate", new Date())
        .append("length", 29179L)
        .append("contentType", "image/jpeg")
        .append("md5", "1402721cc080174ac6ae9c1d51eb68ab")
        // don't forget to add the metadata subdocument
        .append("metadata", metadata);

collection.insertOne(document);

Document insertedDocument = collection.find(Filters.eq("filename", "View000.jpg")).first();
System.out.println(insertedDocument.toJson());
```

The above code will insert his document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b76856dc786a00812246f2c"),
    "filename" : "View000.jpg",
    "aliases" : null,
    "chunkSize" : NumberLong(261120),
    "uploadDate" : ISODate("2018-08-17T08:21:01.835Z"),
    "length" : NumberLong(29179),
    "contentType" : "image/jpeg",
    "md5" : "1402721cc080174ac6ae9c1d51eb68ab",
    "metadata" : {
        "_class" : "eu.ohim.rcd.efi.DocumentEntity",
        "_id" : "RCD201800000001024-0002-0000",
        "provisionalId" : "RCD201800000001024-0002",
        "designApplicationId" : "RCD201800000001024",
        "documentType" : "PROTECTED_VIEW",
        "rcdProtected" : true
    }
}
```